# Can we find two subgroups $A,B \leqslant D_8$ such that $AB \not\leqslant D_8$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Give an example of a group $G$ and two subgroups $A,B \leqslant G$ such that $AB$ is not a subgroup of $G$.

For reference, the presentation of $D_8$ is
$$D_{8} = \langle r,s: r^4 = s^2 = 1, rs = sr^{-1} \rangle.$$

I know that we can find an example that suffices if we inspect $S_3$ already so I am trying to see if I can do the same for $D_8$. Let $A = \langle r \rangle$ and $B = \langle s \rangle$. Then $AB = \langle rs \rangle$, but I suspect that $\langle rs\rangle$ doesn't form a subgroup in $D_8$.

I think that the set $AB$ would not be closed with under inverses. However I haven't been able to convince myself of the fact. Here is my idea so far:

Using the relation $rs = sr^{-1}$, we have
\begin{align}
(rs)(sr^{-1})^{-1} &= e.
\end{align}
Then $(sr^{-1})^{-1} = (s^{-1}r^{-2})$, but that element is not in $AB$. I'm not sure if I am allowed to distribute the inverse though. If I am not, I don't think my argument makes any sense then. Any clarification if I'm taking the right approach or not would be very helpful, thanks.

Comment: Note that $AB=\{ab\mid a\in A, b\in B\}$.  In fact, $AB=D_8$, not $\langle rs\rangle$.

Comment: There is a theorem that if either $A$ or $B$ is normal, then $AB$ must be a subgroup of $D_8$. I guess you may have to consider subgroups that are not normal.

Comment: Note also that, *by definition*, $\langle rs\rangle$ is the smallest *subgroup* of $D_8$ that contains $rs$, so it would necessarily be a subgroup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $B=\langle s\rangle$ and $A=\langle rs\rangle$.  Then $AB=\{e,s,rs,r\}$, is not a subgroup of $D_8$.

Answer (score 3):

There is a very large number of elementary errors in what you write.

First, if $A$ and $B$ are subgroups, then they are not elements. You should not have "$A,B,\in G$", you should have $A,B\subseteq G$ or $A,B\leq G$.

Second, if $A$ and $B$ are subsets/subgroups of a group, then $AB=\{ab\mid a\in A, b\in B\}$. If you take $A=\langle r\rangle = \{1, r, r^2, r^3\}$ and $B=\langle s\rangle = \{1, s\}$, then
$$AB = \{1, r, r^2, r^3, s, rs, r^2s, r^3s\} = D_8,$$
and not, as you claim $\langle rs\rangle$.

Third: by definition, the notation "$\langle X\rangle$" means "the smallest subgroup that contains $X$". So $\langle rs\rangle$ is, by definition, the smallest *subgroup* of $D_8$ that contains $rs$; it would be $\{e,rs\}$, and it is of course a subgroup, *by definition*. You seem to think that $AB=\{rs\}$. This is not true, since $A\neq\{r\}$ (if it were, then it wouldn't be a subgroup *either*), and $B\neq\{s\}$ (same reason).

Three such elementary errors are way too many; one would be bad, two is catastrophic, three is... a very large number.

As it happens, you will not be able to get any examples if $A$ (or $B$) is contained in $\langle r\rangle = \{1,r,r^2,r^3\}$; the reason is that every subgroup of $\langle r\rangle$ is normal in $D_8$, and for a normal subgroup $A$, $AB$ is *always* a subgroup whenever $B$ is a subgroup (though you may not know this yet). So you should look for examples in which neither of the two subgroups is contained in $\langle r\rangle$. And you should really be much more careful with what the objects you are working with *are*. Almost nothing

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my errors. I apologize for all of my elementary errors, I am trying to self-study algebra. I definitely will keep reviewing the basics more..